# How to draw model like plot_model in keras

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a model like following image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `matrix` or `chains`. Here is a version using a `matrix of nodes`. Obviously I did not punch in the texts from your screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>={Latex[bend]}]
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
     ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=3em,row sep=1.5em](mat){
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \\
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \\
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \\
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \\
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \\
  \& 
  \& 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{pft\textunderscore pft\textunderscore}}
     & input & abc \\
     \cline{2-3}
     & output & xyz\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular} 
  \\
    };
 \path (mat-1-1) -- coordinate    (aux1) (mat-1-2)
  (mat-1-2) -- coordinate    (aux2) (mat-1-3);
 \foreach \X in {1,2,3}    
 {\foreach \Y [count=\Z] in {2,...,5}
 {\draw[->] (mat-\Z-\X) -- (mat-\Y-\X);}
 \ifnum\X<3
  \draw[->] (mat-5-\X) to[out=-90,in=-90] (mat-5-\X.south-|aux\X) 
  to[out=90,in=180,looseness=0.6]
  (mat-1-\the\numexpr\X+1);
 \fi
 }
 \draw[->] (mat-5-3) -- (mat-6-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]